# Remove hidden vertices and triangles of cube terrain

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am new here. I was studing procedural terrain with meshes. And i started a make a procedural terrain like Minecraft. And i don't know how i can remove the hidden vertices and triangles in the hidden blocks.

[The hidden vertices and triangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wFNP.png)

**My code:**

**Voxel.cs:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshCollider))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer))]
public class Voxel : MonoBehaviour {

    public Vector3[] vertices;
    public int[] triangles;

    public Vector3 pos;
    public GameObject chunk;
    Mesh mesh;

    public bool blockSolid;

    public Voxel(Vector3 position, GameObject obj)
    {
        pos = position;
        chunk = obj;
    }

    void Start () 
    {
        mesh = new Mesh();

        //Cube(0,0,0);
    }
    
    
    public void Cube(int x, int y, int z)
    {

        GameObject cube = new GameObject("Cubo");
        cube.AddComponent(typeof(MeshFilter));
        cube.AddComponent(typeof(MeshCollider));
        cube.AddComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer));
        cube.transform.parent = chunk.transform;
        mesh = cube.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;

        //cube.transform.position = pos;

        vertices = new Vector3[]
        {
            new Vector3(x,y,z),         // 0
            new Vector3(x,y+1,z),       // 1
            new Vector3(x+1,y+1,z),     // 2
            new Vector3(x+1,y,z),       // 3
            new Vector3(x+1,y,z+1),     // 4
            new Vector3(x+1,y+1,z+1),   // 5
            new Vector3(x,y+1,z+1),     // 6
            new Vector3(x,y,z+1)        // 7
        };

        triangles = new int[]
        {
            0,1,2,  0,2,3,              // Face frontal
            3,2,5,  3,5,4,              // Face direita
            0,7,6,  0,6,1,              // Face esquerda
            7,4,5,  7,5,6,              // Face traseira
            1,6,5,  1,5,2,              // Face superior
            0,3,4,  0,4,7               // Face inferior
        };

        UpdateMesh();
    }

    void UpdateMesh()
    {
        mesh.Clear();

        mesh.vertices = vertices;
        mesh.triangles = triangles;

        mesh.RecalculateNormals();
    }
}
```

**Chunk.cs:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Chunk : MonoBehaviour {

    public int tx, ty, tz;
    public Vector3 pos;

    IEnumerator BuildChunk()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < tx; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < ty; y++)
            {
                for (int z = 0; z < tz; z++)
                {
                    pos = new Vector3(x,y,z);
                    Voxel block = new Voxel(pos, this.gameObject);

                    block.Cube(x,y,z);
                    yield return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void Start () 
    {
        StartCoroutine(BuildChunk());
    }
}
```

I just need to remove the hidden vertices and triangles, but i don't know how i gonna make this.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to generate **only** the triangles that are visible to the player. So you shouldn't be generating cubes for every voxel, but a subset of the faces of a cube.

The way you go about this, is to check all 6 sides of each voxel. If a given side borders another voxel, then ignore that side and move on. If there is no voxel bordering the side, then add the corresponding cube face to that side. This will result in a monolithic mesh encompassing your entire terrain, or the terrain you loaded in.

Comment: Yes, but how i make this? You can modify my code?

Comment: I told you *how* to do it, but nobody's gonna code that for you. I can give you a pointer to where you can find more information though. Check out this site: https://sites.google.com/site/letsmakeavoxelengine/home/chunk-optimizations?authuser=0 it describes how you go about implementing what I described in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, i can't understand yet. I gonna try to verify the x, y and z of my for's and find a way to recognize if have a solid block in the sides of my cubes